# Manifest not found deploying from Travis CI to IBM Bluemix (CloudFoundry)

Tags: manifest, ibm-cloud, travis-ci, cloud-foundry

Simply put, Travis CI reports that CF cannot find the manifest file necessary to deploy my application upon build completion.

> Manifest file is not found in the current directory, please provide either an app name or manifest

[image]

**.travis.yml:**

```
deploy:
  edge: true
  provider: cloudfoundry
  api: $CF_API
  username: $CF_USER
  password: $CF_PASS
  organization: $CF_ORG
  space: $CF_ENV
  on:
    branch: development
```

**manifest.yml:**

```
---
applications:
- name: Website
  memory: 512M
  domain: mybluemix.net
  host: Website
  buildpack: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/php-buildpack.git
```

Both `.travis.yml` and `manifest.yml` are in the root directory as expected.

> [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I had a `cd directory` inside the `before_script` of my `travis.yml`.
Putting said manifest into `directory` fixed it.